# Facebook Analytics shows way too many events recorded

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, in-app-purchase, analytics

I am using Facebook analytics to track purchase of In-apps in my app for iOS. I have also been using another tool for analytics named, Distimo. The issue I had is that the purchases shown by Distimo and those shown in Facebook developers site for my app differ and by a huge number. I have made sure that the Purchases event gets fired only once from my app when an purchase actually happens. Distimo takes the data for analytics from the App Store.

One scenario which I am aware of is that Facebook shows the events according to the Pacific timezone while Distimo shows data by taking the date which the App Store gives it. 
For instance, Say, two downloads occur at the same time:

- 1 in Japan at 1:00 on 2013-09-05
- 1 in Europe at 18:00 on 2013-09-04

In Distimo:
The downloads happened at the same time, but on a different day because of the timezone
difference. In this case, the download in japan would count towards the 5th while the download
in europe would count towards the 4th.

In Facebook:
The download in Japan would count towards 4th at time 9:00 am and the download in Europe would count also count towards 4th at time 9:00am.

However, the difference in the number of events seems to be huge. Is there something I am missing here? I also cannot get the event logs against which I could validate the number of purchases shown in Facebook.

Comment: How are you logging the purchase events in your code?

Comment: I am using the Facebook SDK v4.0 and making the following call to log purchases  `[FBSDKAppEvents logPurchase: currency: parameters:];`

Answer (score 6):

Two thoughts here:

1) have you also enabled automatic in-app purchase logging for iOS in your Facebook app dashboard?  If so, you'll want to remove the explicit call to logPurchase for in-app purchases otherwise these will double log, which could account for your discrepancy.

2) if Distimo is disqualifying non-AppStore-verified purchases (for example, from a jailbroken device), that could account for a discrepancy. Facebook Analytics for Apps doesn't yet do this disqualification.

Comment: These points totally make sense. I will try turning off automatic logging and try to see if I get any difference. Shouldn't matter whether I turn off automatic logging or explicit call right? Either one should solve the issue. What say?

Comment: Correct, either should solve the issue if indeed you were making an explicit call for an iOS in-app purchase and had automatic logging turned on.  It's certainly easier to just turn automatic logging off since it's just a switch on the analytics dashboard and not an app update.

Comment: I have the same problem. I checked that automatic in-app purchase logging for iOS is disabled. I am also logging the same events with Flurry Analytics and the number in Facebook Analytics is still more then double the one in Flurry. Also, I tried viewing the live events on my device in Facebook Event Manager and for every purchase I make it shows four events. Did you ever find an answer to this?